# Azure - getting list of subscriptions and their status out of the EA portal

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm completely lost here - 
I've been trying to get a list of all subscriptions that are in Azure's EA portal (which lists all subscriptions).  In the GUI/web-end, we can only see 10 at a time, and then have to go to the next page, etc. etc.
There's no easy way to export a list of all subscriptions.
I'd like to find a way to export them via powershell, which is apparently possible, but i haven't been able to find ANY info or documentation on it.

Is anyone aware of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the new [`Get-AzSubscriptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/get-azsubscription?view=azps-1.5.0) powershell command to list all the subscriptions your account can access.  You must have an Owner or Contributor role on the Enrollment Account you wish to see subscriptions under.  See our docs on how to [Programmatically create Azure Enterprise subscriptions (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/programmatically-create-subscription?tabs=azure-powershell#prerequisites).  For your purposes, you will use `Get-AzSubscriptions`, not `New-AzSubscriptions`.

Comment: This will iterate only subscriptions the account has access to within the TENANT (or any federation between tenants).  I'm trying to get this visibility at a higher level.  I have access to the EA portal, and can log in with reader access.  From there i can view the subscriptions, but i'm trying to find a way to programmatically obtain that data, such as via an API.